# How can I set the visibility of an ActionBar item in different fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

I'm looking for a way to set the visibility of a `MenuItem` inflated in my MainActivity depending on which `Fragment` I am on.

For information: I'm using `actionBarSherlock`, `zxing`, and some `google services`.

The application was built with a Navigation drawer(With abs), also I manipulate the `FragmentStack` in such way I everytime I switch to another Fragment when I press the touch back I come back in my `Main Fragment`.

Here my menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:id="@+id/button_generator" android:title="GENERER" android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer"></item>
</menu>
```

Here is where I inflate the menu:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.d(TAG, "================= onCreateOptionsMenu ================= fragSt: " + fragmentStatus);
    this.getSherlock().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    mGenQrFromContacts = menu.findItem(R.id.button_generator);


    return true;
}
```

I've tried the solution purposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407667/android-changing-visibility-on-menu-items-with-changing-fragment), but ain't work in my case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should try this in your `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...  
    // call the method setHasOptionsMenu, to have access to the menu from your fragment
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    //...
}

// the create options menu with a MenuInflater to have the menu from your fragment
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.findItem(R.id.button_generator).setVisible(true);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

And this, in your `Activity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_layout, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.button_generator).setVisible(false);
    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly the pattern I use to control action item visibility between multiple fragments (tabs)

Answer (score 1):

when you want to change fragment you will need to set a flag indicating what menu you want inflated then all you have to do is call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` in your activity to call `onCreateOptonsMenu` again and using your flag you set you inflate a different menu

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick, you might wanna try this.

```
public void displayMenu(boolean show) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(show);
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```